# How could I find out why my https request failed?

Tags: curl, https, caddy

I have three computers, and I deployed Caddy on computer A as a server.
Once finished, I tested the api on computer B, and I found both http/https requests worked as expected.
But on computer C, http request worked fine, while https request returned a 'timeout' error.

So, how could I find out why https request failed on computer C?

I logged the output of Caddy, and the log was printed when a http request sent from computer C. But if I sent a https request from computer C, the log printed nothing.
Any idea how to find out the problem?

Comment: Check the firewall config on each computer and trace your network using Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can debug, then the detail will print in console:

```
{
  debug
}
```